# How to get more info on julia array bounds error?

Tags: julia

I'd coded a Julia function with an array bounds error:

```
function wrong()

   alphas = [ 0.5, 1, 1.25, 2.0 ] ;
   theta = 0:0.02:1 * pi ;
   U = zeros( length(theta), 4 ) ;

   i = 1 ;
   j = 1 ;
   for a = alphas
      kd = pi * a ;

      for t = theta
         v = (cos( kd * cos( t ) ) - cos( kd ))/sin( t ) ;

         U[i, j] = v ;

         i = i + 1 ;
      end

      j = j + 1 ;
   end
end
```

Here i=1 should be in the loop.  I get:

```
julia> wrong()
ERROR: BoundsError()
 in setindex! at array.jl:308 (repeats 2 times)
```

Is there any way to get the julia interpreter to give more detailed information about exceptions when they are hit, or ways to debug into the failing statement and see what's going on?  For example, knowing what the index values that were caused the bounds error when this occurred would have been helpful to debug this.

Comment: Irrelevant, superficial, nit-picky stylistic details: It's considered better style in Julia to increment with `+=` and to avoid ending statements with a semicolon.

Comment: += I can do, but the semicolons are going to be a hard habit to break since I write mostly in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bounds error reporting has improved in julia v0.4 via this pull request https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/9534. In julia 0.4 the array as well as the index you were trying to access get printed by default:

```
julia> wrong()
ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 158x4 Array{Float64,2}:
 NaN           0.0  0.0  0.0
   0.0157085   0.0  0.0  0.0
   0.0314201   0.0  0.0  0.0
   0.047138    0.0  0.0  0.0
   0.0628651   0.0  0.0  0.0
   0.0786045   0.0  0.0  0.0
   0.094359    0.0  0.0  0.0
   0.110131    0.0  0.0  0.0
   0.125924    0.0  0.0  0.0
   0.141739    0.0  0.0  0.0
   ⋮
   0.127183    0.0  0.0  0.0
   0.111388    0.0  0.0  0.0
   0.0956143   0.0  0.0  0.0
   0.0798585   0.0  0.0  0.0
   0.064118   0.0  0.0  0.0
   0.04839     0.0  0.0  0.0
   0.0326715   0.0  0.0  0.0
   0.0169595   0.0  0.0  0.0
   0.00125087  0.0  0.0  0.0
  at index [159,2]
 in wrong at none:15
```

I don't know if you can backport the changes to your julia version, but switching to 0.4 should solve your problem.